# Get coordinates for multiple points automatically in Leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have created a fictional map using `MapTiler` and `Leafletjs` which contains hundreds of points that I want to reference from my code. I created a reference marker in `Leafletjs` which I can drag to a specific location on my map and get the pixel coordinates.

I now need to do the same for all these hundreds of points in order to generate a key/value pair of `[location_name as key, coordinates as value]`. If I do that manually it will probably take me weeks.

Is there an automated approach that I could follow in `Leaflet` that will allow me to retrieve the coordinates easier? The map was originally a vector image which I converted to png and then using `MapTiler` to all the different sizes `Leafletjs` needs.

The code below shows how the reference marker works:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([60, 0], 0);

    L.tileLayer('{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 5,
      minZoom: 1,
      continuousWorld: false,
      noWrap: true,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([70, 0], {
      draggable: true,  
    }).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup('<b>Test</b>').openPopup();

    marker.on('dragend', function(e) {
      alert(marker.getLatLng().toString()); 
    });
```

Comment: Ugh. That is terrible to read. How about some whitespace, formatting, and some code?

Comment: Wow, things have moved on in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Look at the difference now.

Comment: That is already a big help for my tired eyes :)

Comment: Any idea how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Thinking. Not sure I quite get quite what you mean, if you made the markers surely you have them already? Code would help. Can you post an image of  the map and the markers and the code that made it? As an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113033/discussion-between-dimitris-and-mike-wise).

Comment: Don't really feel like chatting - feel like solving a problem. Post some code, or I go on to the next problem.

Comment: I have a reference marker that I can drag around the map and whenever I stop I have a popup that essentially gives me pixel coordinates
So for example let's say we are looking at the London map, I can drag the marker to Paddington and get the pixel coordinates there. Now what I want is to get the pixel coordinates on all the major areas of London such as Ealing, Paddington, Marble Arch, etc
If I drag the reference marker on all those areas it will take me forever

Comment: I was pulled into a meeting. Will have to get to this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better workflow would be something like:

- Add a `click` event handler in the map, so that new markers can be created
- Add those newly created markers to a globally accesible array
- Make all markers draggable
- Add a button outside of the map, which can `console.log()` all the markers at once (then copy-paste)

Without knowing the original format of the data, it's difficult to see if the data could be converted automatically, but making a quick tool to ease the pain of locating a few hundred points is doable.

Comment: It's a good workflow but still time consuming to go through each area in the map from the hundreds I 've got. Essentially I have labels in my map for 300 hundreds neighbourhoods of London and I want to get the coordinates for each one of them.

Comment: But if you've made image tiles, then you've rasterized those labels... being part of the images, it's not possible to extract them. Without knowing the original format of your hand-made map, it's not really possible to think about better solutions.

Comment: The original map is a vector image so potentially I could use that but I am new to Leaflet and started this by using the PNG approach.

Comment: Leaflet will only use the tiled PNG images - if you want to extract the coordinates, you'll have to do so *before* creating the tiled PNGs. Try to convert your vector data to something that `Leaflet.Omnivore` can understand.

Comment: Just looking on the web for articles on this. Any recommendations to get an idea of what it is and how it works?